# Compose new JSON based on field in large array of objects with Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I’m receiving JSON that is not grouped in a good way. For each "field" that has been updated in an HR-system, I receive an object with many unnecessary fields. The objects only have three values that I’m interested in, "uniqueId", "field" and "value".

```
[
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30362",
        "field": "DateOfBirth",
        "value": "1980-12-01"
Lots of more unnecessary fields... 
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30362",
        "field": "StartDate",
        "value": "2020-01-01"
Lots of more unnecessary fields... 
    },
{
        "uniqueId": "Env30363",
        "field": "DateOfBirth",
        "value": "1980-12-01"
Lots of more unnecessary fields... 
    },
    Lots of objects with different uniqueId…
]
```

I would like to get all the "fields" and "values" that are associated to a uniqueId and create a new JSON, where uniqueId is Env30362 for example.

```
{
"uniqueId": "Env30362",
"StartDate”: "2020-01-01",
"DateOfBirth": "1980-12-01"
etc..
}
```

How can I achieve this with Logic Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to my `azure logic app`:

I defined a json string as input：

[image]

You can use [Parse JSON action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action) to parse your JSON, you can click `Use sample payload to generate schema` and paste your json into it to generate the schema.

[image]

Define an array to get all the `uniqueId` in a loop.

[image]

[image]

You can use the following expression to remove the redundant `uniqueId`.

Expression:

```
union(variables('uniqueIdArr'),variables('uniqueIdArr'))
```

[image]

Loop the `uniqueId` array, and then use the [Filter array action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#filter-array-action) to filter out the items that contain the same `uniqueId`.

Expression:

```
array(json(variables('jsonString')))

string(item())

body('Filter_array')[2]?['value']

body('Filter_array')[1]?['value']
```

[image]
[image]

Input json string：

```
[
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30362",
        "field": "DateOfBirth",
        "value": "1980-12-01",
        "test1": "value1"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30362",
        "field": "StartDate",
        "value": "2020-01-01",
        "test1": "value2"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30363",
        "field": "DateOfBirth",
        "value": "1980-12-01",
        "test1": "value1"
    },
        {
        "uniqueId": "Env30363",
        "field": "DateOfBirth",
        "value": "1980-12-01",
        "test1": "value1"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30363",
        "field": "StartDate",
        "value": "2020-01-01",
        "test1": "value2"
    },
    {
        "uniqueId": "Env30362",
        "field": "DateOfBirth",
        "value": "1980-12-01",
        "test1": "value1"
    }
]
```